# Feynman exercise - container with steel balls

Tags: homework-and-exercises

You received many steel balls of the same diameter d and container of known volume V. All dimensions of the container are much greater than balls diameter. How many balls can be placed in a container?

Could it be a correct solution?

To place balls in a container we should arrange this container with in a certain order. Let's assume that this balls will be organised such that centres every eight of the bullets will be in vertices of cube. Of course, the length of side of the cube will be equal in diameter of bullet d. For each cube one bullet. Calculating using this formula $(\frac{4}{3}\pi)(d^3/8)\approx 0,52 d^3$ we conclude that bullets occupy 52% of the available area.

Answer (score 1):

No, placing the spheres at he vertices of a cube is not the most efficient packing. The most efficient packing of spheres is in a face-centred-cubic arrangement. The volume taken up is 74%. Computing this value follows a similar procedure to what you used.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_crystal_system